# Get all .log extensions from directory and all subdirectories

Tags: docker, command-line, docker-compose, terminal, grafana-loki

I am new to Linux. I am currently working with docker, more specifically Loki and Promtail. One of the things I wanted to log is docker container logs. The thing I don't know is how to correctly write a path so that Promtail can grab all .log exstensions from a defined path directory and all it's subdirectories. Docker container logs are located in var/lib/docker/containers/<container_id>/ directories.

Promtail config:

```
- job_name: dockerContainers
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: dockerContainers
      __path__: /var/lib/docker/containers/*.log
```

I also tried   `/var/lib/docker/containers/**/*/*.log`  but that also did not work. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
__path__: /var/lib/docker/containers/**/*.log
```